# Multiple event listeners for "input" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, handler, jquery-events

I know you can add multiple event listeners for the "click" event like this:

```
$("input").bind("click",function(e){
        console.log("one");
    })
$("input").bind("click",function(e){
        console.log(two);
    })
```

But how its possible to add multiple event listeners for the "input" event?
I tried this but it seems it gets only the last event listener:

```
$("input").bind("input",function(e){
        console.log("one");
    })
$("input").bind("input",function(e){
        console.log("two");
    })
```

I get only "two" in the console when I type something.

This is the result of the `console.log($._data( $("input")[0], "events" ));`:

```
Object {click: Array[2], input: Array[1]}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fekpo3a7/

Comment: I am not sure what you trying here. you attaching a same event twice to same set of elements?

Comment: Just to make sure, it's `console.log('two');`, not `console.log(two);`.

Comment: @minseong It seems that my code is wrong(I use it in a different context)

Comment: Problem solved. It seemed I had some "bad code" in my script. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have problems:check this out
http://jsbin.com/sisozisoko/1/edit?html,js,output
but i think its going to be better to reorganize your code:

```
var printOne = function(e){
        console.log("one");
    },
    printTwo = function(e){
        console.log("two");
    };
$("input").on("click", function () {
    printOne();
    printTwo();
});
```

the property bind is not used anymore: http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Comment: "the property bind is deprecated", input(), focus() and other event related **methods** are shortcuts for bind('blah')!

Comment: bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},

Comment: not really but is a good practice use on because at the end it's gonna be used.

Comment: @ariel_556 It doesn't make it deprecated, from the docs: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().`, I doesn't say it's deprecated.